# displaying the value of a checkbox in a div with javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

In my application I will eventually want to dynamically assign values to certain checkbox values but where I am at currently is this.

When the page first loads, a set of checkboxes load and when any of these are checked, a corresponding div is revealed nearby.  In THAT div there is an additional checkbox that drops down a section of text that should match what the value of the original checkbox value is.

I have the click a box, reveal a box, click a box, reveal the text part working correctly but what it displays is hardcoded and I'm trying to figure out how to pass the values of the checkboxes around to tie everything together dynamically. Thank you for your assistance on this.

Comment: keeping the values of your checkboxes in an array and applying them to where needed would be one solution, keeping the interactive and persistent display parts separate.

Comment: Better than trying to explain your HTML, simply post it (the parts that are important to understand the problem).

Comment: Also, I would use `data-` attributes on the parent checkboxes to store the "text" in. Simpler to implement and it keeps content with content, and code with code.